# Control Pi from RedHat terminal

Tags: raspbian, linux, vnc

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 that I connected to a laptop and I am trying to control the Pi from my other laptop that has a Red Hat virtual machine installed. I have connected them using an ethernet cable and a USB cable using VNC viewer but all I can do is see the Pi's desktop.

Am I able to somehow control the Pi, for example running commands on it from the gnome terminal on my RedHat machine?

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify *"I have connected them together using an ethernet cable and an [sic] usb cable using VNC viewer but all I can do is see the Pi's interface on my desktop"*.  Presumably you mean, "I have connected them together with an ethernet cable and a usb cable **and I am trying to use VNC viewer** but...". I.e., you are asking how to use VNC viewer?

Comment: Note the USB cable (picky tangent: that's *a* USB cable, because you-ess-bee does not start with a vowel, and writing follows speech in this case) is sort of irrelevant in that it is just for power BUT there is a good chance the port on your laptop will not provide sufficient power for a Pi 3.  Is the red LED flickering at all?

Comment: OK, sorry, it's my first question and I'm new to all of this.

Comment: I succeeded to connect them using VNC viewer but what I want is to control the pi from the gnome terminal on my RedHat machine. With VNC all I can do is see the PI's desktop

Comment: For future reference if you are adding more information/clarifying the question, edit it into the question ;)  You can then just leave a comment something like, "I've added the information to the question above".

Comment: I'm unsure sure if you're tied to VNC or not, but you can always try NoMachine if you absolute need remote GUI/Desktop access:
https://www.nomachine.com/tips-on-how-to-set-up-your-raspberry-pi-for-remote-access-via-nomachine

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you just want a remote command prompt, [SSH](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/protocol/) is the standard tool (it will do graphical X forwarding too, but that is slightly more complicated).

To enable the server on a Pi using Raspbian, add a file named `ssh` to `/boot` (aka. the small first vfat partition) and reboot.

You then need to install the openssh client on the RedHat VM, if it is not there already.  The command to connect is:

```
ssh pi@123.456.789
```

Where `123.456.789` is the appropriate IP address (if avahi is working, you may be able to use `raspberry.pi`).  You will then be prompted for the `pi` user password.  After that you should see the command prompt from the Pi.